# Find the control that an Attached Property is attached to in the OnChange Event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

Say I have the following Code:

```
   public static DependencyProperty LabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Label",
            typeof(Label),
            typeof(HotKeyHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Label), OnLabelChanged)
        );

    public static void SetLabel(DependencyObject obj, Label value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(LabelProperty, value);
    }

    public static Label GetLabel(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Label)obj.GetValue(LabelProperty);
    }

    private static void OnLabelChanged(DependencyObject obj,
         DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Label label = obj as Label;

        // Question is for Right Here!
    }
```

Is there a way in the OnLabelChanged event to get the object it is attached to?

For example, say I use this like this:

```
  <TextBox Controls:HotKeyHelper.Label="{Binding ElementName=SomeLabel}"/>
```

Is there a way to get a reference to the SomeLabel label in my OnLabelChanged event?

Comment: `obj` should be the object the attached property is set on, i doubt that you'll want to cast it to `Label` as it can be anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`e.NewValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertychangedeventargs.newvalue.aspx)?

obj should be the object the attached property is set on, i doubt that you'll want to cast it to Label as it can be anything...